# Number of closed binary operations which have an identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, binary-operations

Let $M=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be a set. What is the number of closed binary operations defined on $M$ which have an identity?
My approach : Let $a_1$ be the identity. Considering the Cayley Table of the binary operation, the column and the row of $a_1$ are perfectly determined since it is the identity.
We are left with counting the number of functions from a set with $n^2-2n+1$ elements to a set with $n$ elements. This is equal to $n^{n^2-2n+1}$.
The same reasoning works for all $a_i$, $i=\overline{1,n}$. As a result, the number of closed binary operations defined on $M$ which have an identity is $n^{n^2-2n+2}$.
I would like to know if my approach is correct.

Comment: Is a *closed* binary operation different from a regular binary operation?

Comment: Otherwise, yes, I think your counting argument is sufficient.  Without further conditions, the rest of the Cayley table can be arbitrary.

Comment: Looks OK to me (quick reading) and gives the correct answer for $n=1$ and  $n=2$. You should specify two-sided identity explicitly.

Comment: @rschwieb closed means that $\forall x, y \in M \implies xy \in M$.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks! I thought that it was obvious that the identity is two-sided since I hadn't specified that it was only one-sided.

Comment: @Alexdanut Thank goodness. I wonder where $xy$ would be otherwise if not in $M$ :)  I'm pretty sure a huge majority of authors would require that to be true for just a "binary operation."

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. The only way this could be wrong would be if there were binary operations which had two identities, because such operations would be counted twice by your method. However, it is well known that any operation has at most one (two-sided) identity.